# Different virtual hosts (Apache) for different subdirectories?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I want to host a webpage for 150 users. Each user will have a unique webpage by the url `url/username/index.html`.  Here **username** is unique for all users rest all remains common.

So do I need to make 150 virtual hosts in Apache Server or is there some other way out?

Comment: Is `url` something like `http://example.com` or something like `http://example.com/path/to/userdirs`?

Comment: `url` is something like `http://example.com/username/index/html` where **username** will vary for different users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enable per-user web directories with [mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/public_html.html) which maps

```
http://example.com/~username/index.html
```

to the corresponding file

```
/home/username/public_html/index.html
```

in the user directory per default.

To get rid of the tilde, you could use Apache's rewrite engine and forbid access to all URLs starting with `~` and use `Alias`es to map the individual paths to their user directories.

Add this to your VirtualHost config:

```
RewriteEngine On
# forbid URLs starting with /~
RewriteRule ^/~  -  [F]

# map individual paths to user dirs
Alias /bart    /home/bart/public_html
Alias /homer   /home/homer/public_html
Alias /lisa    /home/lisa/public_html
Alias /maggie  /home/maggie/public_html
# ...
```

If you don't need to serve any files from your `DocumentRoot`, you could use one `AliasMatch` instead of 150 `Alias`es:

```
# map all paths to user dirs
AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$  /home/$1/public_html$2
```

You need to enable `mod_userdir` and `mod_rewrite` in your server, on Debian you would do this with `a2enmod` and a restart.

```
sudo a2enmod userdir rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot even be done with virtual hosts because you would need different host names (or ports) for telling them apart.

This is just one host with subdirectories for different users. So you may have to (or at least want) to set different file permissions for each of those subdirectories.